# A part of mesh turn into cyan in edit mode

Tags: modeling

I am a newbie in blender. I just had a trouble with modeling.
I did a model in Zbrush, then I import that in maya to retopologize.
then I import the retopologized model into blender.
Problem is when I switch the mesh into edit mode, a part of mesh will become cyan color. 
this is different from what I usually did.

[image]

Hanwen 
Thanks

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/85012/54300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those edges are marked as sharp. If faces & edges are marked as smooth blender will simulate a smooth edge. Shading is computed from the direction of the edge normals. They will merge into one when smoothed.

[image]

If you want rid of the blue lines (yellow in my viewport) select everything and set all edges to smooth. If you want to play around with smooth/sharp faces and edges set all faces to smooth and enable auto-smooth (and perhaps increase the angle to 180). The relevant buttons are marked in red below.

[image]